# update attribute in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

Here is my form

```
<%= form_for @post do |f| %>
    <div class="input">
    <div class="input-label"><label for="title">Title</label></div>
    <div class="input-txt"><%= f.text_field :title %></div>
    </div>
    <div class="input">
    <div class="input-label"><label for="login">Description</label></div>
    <div class="input-txt txt-area"><%= f.text_area :description %></div>
    </div>

        #This will load dynamic  select boxes through ajax
        <%= select_tag label.head_name, options_for_select(generate_option(label)) %>
<% end %>
```

I am updating the above form

```
def update_ctrl
    @post = Post.find_by_id post_id
    @post.update_attributes(post_params) #This works
    @post.update_attributes(content: params[:style]) #This is not working
end  


private
    def post_params
        params.require(:post).permit(:title,:description)
     end
```

How do i solve it how to get the select_tag params in my controller. Is there any way to do it

Comment: We'd need more information as to what is in those `params`. You've allowed `:title` and `:description` in [strong parameters](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html), but not the `:style` attribute that you're trying to update. What happens with `@post.update(content: params[:style])`?

Comment: @d_ethier something tells me that `style` belongs to another class.

Comment: style is dynamically created name for select that is `<select name="style">`

Comment: @d_ethier I am unable to update the params[:style]

Comment: Ah, @David, you're right. Read it too quickly. In this instance, you would have to add content to the strong parameters list in `post_params`. When you say it isn't working, are you getting an error message? That would be helpful as well.